# Create foreign key rows at the same time as creating a row that depends on them?

Tags: postgresql

Hello I would like to be able to automatically create all related rows that depend on the row that I want to insert.  For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE application (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    client_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE    
);

CREATE TABLE user (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE access_token (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    token VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES user(id),
    application_id INTEGER REFERENCES application(id)
);

CREATE TABLE profile (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    nickname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES user(id),
    application_id INTEGER REFERENCES application(id)
);

-- The application will already exist
INSERT INTO application (client_id) VALUES ('9fe9bae2b3ba4041a0a24e3c863129eb');
```

I would like to insert a row into the `profile` table.  In order to do that I have to 1) Lookup the FK for the application (I only have the `client_id`), 2) Insert new rows for `user` and `access_token`.  The user and access token will always be inserted, they wont exist already.

At the end of it I would like to get back the profile.id, profile.nickname, profile.created_at, application.client_id, access_token.token.

I'm trying the WITH construct but having trouble getting this to work, keep getting errors.

I've tried:

```
WITH APPLICATION AS (
    SELECT id, client_id FROM ben_application WHERE client_id = '9fe9bae2b3ba4041a0a24e3c863129eb'
), "USER" AS (
    INSERT INTO ben_user (username) VALUES ('ben') RETURNING id
), ACCESS_TOKEN AS (
    INSERT INTO ben_access_token (token, user_id, application_id) VALUES ('token', "USER".id, APPLICATION.id) RETURNING token
)
INSERT INTO ben_profile (nickname, user_id, application_id) VALUES ('Ben W', "USER".id, APPLICATION.id)
RETURNING id, nickname, created_at, APPLICATION.client_id, ACCESS_TOKEN.token;
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "USER"
LINE 6: ...(token, user_id, application_id) VALUES ('token', "USER".id,...
```

I feel like I'm on the right track, but still pretty far off considering this wont execute.  Any help is appreciated!

This is PostgreSQL server 11.9

Comment: `USER` is a reserved word, see here [Reserved](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Either change that name or quote it.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ahh thank you!  See edit, I've fixed the reserved-word error but getting something new

Comment: Why not simply use multiple statements? I see no reason why creating a profile should give the user an access token.

Comment: your problem is that the isnert isn't finished when you rin your CTE, so your constrict doesn't work as you noticed. You ahve to use temporary tables to achieve what you wnat

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, you are missing a `FROM` clause, and consequently a `SELECT` in the second `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO ben_access_token (...)
SELECT ..., "USER".id, ... FROM "USER";
```